# error for unused variable, gem5

Tags: python, c, scons, unused-variables, gem5

I am using scons to compile gem5.

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.fast -j4
```

I have defined a variable, initialized it and used it in dprintf statement.

```
Addr tot_blk_count = page_number / page_per_block; 
DPRINTF(out, "Total block count %lu " , tot_blk_count);
```

However, scons will report errors (not warning) for unused variables.

```
 error: unused variable 'tot_blk_count' [-Werror=unused-variable]
```

Any suggestion on how to get rid of this error, or change it to warning?

Comment: Apparently, gem5.fast ignores the DPRINTF statement, cause error of unused variable. I changed this to scons build/ARM/gem5.opt and compile was successful.

Comment: You should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

While compiling for gem5.fast DPRINTF will be ignored, and tot_blk_count will be an unused variable.

Solutions:

One solution is to compile for gem5.opt, since it will not ignore the DPRINTF and no error will be reported.

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

Second solution is to use the statement inside DPRINTF to avoid unused variable in case you are compiling for gem5.fast:

```
DPRINTF(out, "Total block count %lu " , page_number / page_per_block);
```

In case you want to keep the declaration of the unused variable, simply mark it with M5_VAR_USED, which will inform the compiler that the variable is possibly unused and no warning will be triggered:

```
Addr M5_VAR_USED tot_blk_count = page_number / page_per_block; 
DPRINTF(out, "Total block count %lu " , tot_blk_count);
```